# Center the subview in UIView using constraints in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

i have three subview like subview1,subview2,subview3 in a `UIViewController` inside a `UIView`.

I'm using constraints on them, the constraints which i'm using to show then in a center when the button is clicked are these,

- Horizantally in Container,
- Vertically in Container,
- width and
- height.

**Issue :**

When I run the app and click the `button` once it comes in the right position. But when i dismiss it and try again to open it, the `subview` change its position itself and comes on the **top left** of the `UIViewcontroller` ,

As you can see in a screen shot, but i want to show the `view` every time when i click the button in the **center** of the `UIViewcontroller`.

I'm confused that constraints are right but why it always changes its position when we open it again.

[image]

My code is ,

```
    - (IBAction)Precord:(id)sender {

       _DateView.hidden=NO;
        [self.DateView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft];
    }
```

The contents in story board are like this ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBYd0.png)

Comment: You need to refresh the layout constraints. after clicking button, try   yourView.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: the layout constraints you have created will place the subview in center. First time it shows propertly. After dismissing the view and adding again to parent view, the subview constraints are not applied. So refresh them by calling layoutIfNeeded() method on subview.

Comment: Please show some code, so we can help you better, are you setting constraints programmatically or using storyboard?

Comment: @Oneeb Show me your storyboard for this UIViewController. And your View Hierarchy structure and constraints.

Comment: add self.DateView.layoutIfNeeded() after [self.DateView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft]; line and check

Comment: Calling object type void is not a function, i'm getting this error after writing a line u have written. @ios_dev

Comment: issue is that, that i have s subview in my view controller which opens on a button click. I have set it constraints to show it in the center when it opens, When i click the button it open the view at the exact location but when i dismiss the view and open it again it changes it position and display on the top left of the view controller as u can see in my screen shot. @ios_dev

Comment: @Oneeb try UIView -> updateConstraints() method. As per apple docs, "If you want to change a constraint in response to a button tap, make that change directly in the button’s action method.".  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints

Comment: One more option, remove position constraints and  add constraints only for size to subview and for positioning, set subview.center = parentview.center

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you are dismissing the View. I just tried below code and it worked for me

```
- (IBAction)btn_Tapped:(id)sender {
_smallView.hidden = false;
[_smallView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft];
}
 - (IBAction)hide_Tapped:(id)sender {
_smallView.hidden = true;
}
```

Basically i am just hiding the view. And when btn_Tapped, everytime the view is displaying with bouncing animation in the center. Let me know how you go!

Comment: it changes its potion. @Deepika

Comment: I have tried this code myself and it was not changing position for me. Are you removing the view from its parentView at any point of time?

Comment: no, i'm not but i have used an animation when i click the button first it comes to right position and then it comes to the top left. @Deepika

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yourSubView.center = CGPointMake(yourMainView.frame.size.width  / 2, 
                             yourMainView.frame.size.height / 2);
```

Comment: U have give also frame with this

Comment: I have just created a subview and center position it and applied constraints, i have used animation also for this subview. @Vikas Rajput

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to programmatically add constrains. Modify it with your desire size.

Notice 1: toItem: self, where self is just a view where u added the subView.

Notice 2:  SubView MUST be added to self or a subView of self.

```
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .height,  relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height,  multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .width,   relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width,   multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

I would recommend adding constrains in Storyboard. Easier to see/read, clear code and error validator.

On your problem i would say it a animation problem. Just before adding your view run again the method that set the view frames/constrains (to reset the animation position modification).

Or just when animation is finish, instead of hiding the view, remove it from super view. And when u need it again, just add it again.

Comment: Its giving some syntax error in ur code where u have written .isActive=true, it is point out to add ; semicolon there but when i add it shows another error. @alegelos